# optional warning message leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the code below i warn the user "leaving page" unless the user presses the send button. 
But if the user fills in no form boxes, can i stop "leaving page" warning?
No form box is filled in + send button is pressed = **no warning**
Any form box is filled in or the user wants to leave the page or go back= **show "leaving page" warning**

```
var warning = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 

  if (warning) { return "You have made changes on this page that you have not yet confirmed. If you navigate away from this page you will lose your unsaved changes";

}

}

$('form').submit(function() {

   window.onbeforeunload = null;

});
```

Comment: ugh, i HATE it when sites do this. It's a sure fire way to make me think twice about coming back

Comment: but yes, it is possible. in your `.submit()` callback, have a condition for each of the form elements to check if there's a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to base the behavior on the contents of the form elements, you'll need to either check their contents or listen to changes in their contents to configure your unload behavior.

Checking the form contents is probably fastest, since you'll only need to do it in the case the user actually tries to navigate away, you won't need to manage a bunch of listeners on all the form elements (and have them firing events you no longer care about once the user has started modification).

Comment: My english is not very good. 
Can you show me a sample code?

I will be grateful to you.